# What motivated the term 'oblique'?

Tags: terminology

<sub>Source: p 137, *Syntax, A Generative Introduction* (3 ed, 2012) by Andrew Carnie</sub>

> xxix) ***Oblique***: any NP/PP in the sentence that is not a subject, direct
>   object of a preposition, direct object, or indirect object.

I understand the definition above, but what motivated the choice of this term?
I am conjecturing the word choice not to be random.

Comment: It comes from Latin, meaning among other things "indirect", and has been used in language studies since Hector was a pup.

Answer (score 5):

Casus rectus and Casus obliquus are calques on πτῶσις ὀρθή (“upright fall”) and πτῶσις πλαγία (“sideways fall”) respectively. It has been suggested that these were originally technical terms in a game of dice.